# How to solve the error in php database connection?

Tags: php, forms

I am developing a form with database connection using oops concept.
All my code is correct but i cannot find the error.
This is my index.php .

```
<form class="" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="">
<label for="name-element">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="" id="" name="rSName"  value=""/>
<label for="mob-element">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="" id="" name="rsMob"  value=""/>
<label for="date-element">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="" id="" name="rsDate"  value=""/>
<label for="email-element">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="" id="" name="rSEmail"  value=""/>
<label for="birdath-element">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="" id="" name="rsBirDate"  value=""/>
<label for="submit-element">Name</label>
<input type="submit" class="" id="" name="submit"  value="submit"/>
```

this is my database.php .

```
class database
{
    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $database;


    protected function connect()
    {
        $this->servername = "localhost";
        $this->username = "root";
        $this->password = "";
        $this->database = "ooss";

        $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

        return $conn;


}
}
```

and i have a file for storing data as store.php .

```
<?php

include "database.php";

/**Store all the data into the database
 * 
 */
class store extends database
{

    public function storeAllData($FullName,  $BirthDay, $Email,$Date,$Mobile)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO feedback(rSName,  rsBirDate, rSEmail,rsDate,rsMob)VALUES('$FullName',  '$BirthDay', '$Email','$Date','$Mobile')";
        $result  = $this->connect()->query($sql);

        return $result;

    }
}

?>
```

This code is at the top of the index.php file.

```
include 'store.php';
$stores = new store();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $FullName = $_POST['rSName'];   
  $BirthDay = $_POST['rsBirDate'];  
  $Email = $_POST['rSEmail']; 
  $Mobile = $_POST['rsMob'];  
  $Date = $_POST['rsDate'];  

 $res = $stores->storeAllData($FullName, $BirthDay, $Email, $Date,$Mobile);
 if($res){
  echo "Successfully inserted";
 }  else {
  echo " Not successfull";
 }
```

I run this code, and got as "Not successful".

This is something strange even my code is fine and easy.

Comment: in your `connect` you should check if `$conn` has an error, as suggested in the php manual for the mysqli constructor (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php - in "examples") in general, how do you think you'll notice when you do a mistake in your queries, if you don't really check the results "oops" style?

Comment: If you insert data to database, you need to commit it. See [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php).

Comment: I'm not sure, but don't you need a space in fromnt of VALUES in the SQL statement?